# Magento 2.3 : How custom router works?

Tags: magento2, router

I created custom router in custom extension. For eg. : I created 5 custom extension and in all extension there are custom router available.

Now, when i execute url like this : http://127.0.0.1/mg231/en/testing1 It will go for check in all extension's custom router file.

But, this url is for 1st extension.

Is it feasible way?

Should it be working like if executed url is related to 1st extension url then it should be only check in 1st extension's custom router.

**1st extension :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="test1" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">33</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**2nd Extension :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="test2" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">34</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Please help me.

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have created multiple extension with customRouter but

```
        <item name="customrouter" xsi:type="array">
```

Type will stay remain same  means customrouter for all

so it will check all until it get instance of particular router

Comment: No. Name also different.

Comment: please add your di.xml of all different extension

Comment: please check it

Comment: Any update . . . .?

Comment: Hello @Rutvee any update please?